# Is there a change in handling of wildcard expansion in gmake v4.1 and gmake v4.2.1

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, gnu-make, linux-mint

I have the following target defined in my Makefile

```
%/$(BINFILE_NAME).rom :%/main.riscv
```

This works on my local machine which has the following configuration

```sh
 make -v
GNU Make 4.2.1

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description:    Linux Mint 20
Release:    20
Codename:   ulyana

uname -a
Linux dyumnin 5.4.0-40-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 00:01:04 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But on a remote machine I see the build fail with the following error message

`No rule to make target '/home/me/project/test/config/ts/rx_DELETEME/outdir/mem.rom', needed by 'default'.  Stop.`

the configuration on the remote side is

```sh
make -v
GNU Make 4.1

lsb_release -a  
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

uname -a
Linux foo_server 4.15.0-111-generic #112-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 9 20:32:34 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is there any known change between the two version of Make that could cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

The more probable cause is that `main.riscv` is not present on your remote system. The following demonstrates the effect:

```
all: foo.bar

%.bar : %.baz
        touch $@

%.baz:
       touch $@
```

Output:

```
touch foo.baz
touch foo.bar
rm foo.baz
```

In pattern rules, if you take away the knowledge how to construct a `.baz` file *and also there is no matching file present in the file system*, not the missing `.baz` but the target depending on it is being admonished:

```
all: foo.bar

%.bar : %.baz
        touch $@

#%.baz:
#       touch $@
```

Result:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'foo.bar', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
```